# Distribute a certain value based or Ranking in Redshift

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

```
+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| Time_of_transaction | Customer_id |  Order_id  | Order_Value | Eligible_discount | Applicable_Discount |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 11/1/2019 12:34     |        1234 | 8682686399 |         100 | 10                | 10                  |
| 11/2/2019 12:14     |        1234 |  144141455 |          20 | 2                 | 2                   |
| 11/5/2019 22:14     |        1234 | 1424535235 |          45 | 4.5               | 4.5                 |
| 11/7/2019 9:14      |        1234 |  463637675 |          65 | 6.5               | 3.5                 |
| 11/7/2019 10:20     |        1234 |   12242144 |          30 | 3                 | 0                   |
| 11/7/2019 18:10     |        1234 |  141351555 |          80 | 8                 | 0                   |
| 12/1/2019 12:34     |        5678 |  124421552 |         230 | 23                | 20                  |
| 12/2/2019 12:14     |        5678 |  357757757 |         130 | 13                | 0                   |
| 12/5/2019 22:14     |        5678 |   28668890 |          80 | 8                 | 0                   |
| 12/7/2019 9:14      |        5678 |   68568889 |         120 | 12                | 0                   |
| 12/7/2019 10:20     |        5678 |  314124455 |          45 | 4.5               | 0                   |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I have a table as shown. The table has 5 columns, 
Time_of_transaction,
Customer_id,
Order_Id,
Order_Value and 
Eligible_discount.

Eligible_discount is nothing but 10% of the Order_Value.
Now i want to give discount to the customers based on their transaction time but the discount is 
capped at maximum 20 dollar per customer. Applicable_Discount present in the data is the column i want to calculate.
I am using the below code to sort the data based on customer_id and Time_of_transaction but I am not aware how to calculate the Applicable_Discount column. Need help to build a query for Redshift.

```
   select Time_of_transaction, Customer_id, Order_id,Order_Value, 
0.1*Order_Value as Eligible_discount,
row_number() over 
(partition by Customer_id
 order by Time_of_transaction asc) as row
from cust_tran_info
order by 2,1
```

Comment: mysql or postgresql?

Comment: It sems you want `LEAST(0.1*stuff,20)`

Answer (score 2):

### $20 cap imposed at an order level

Calculating your applicable discount should simply be `least(Order_Value * 0.1, 20)`, i.e. your order value * 10% capped at 20.

```
select  Time_of_transaction,
        Customer_id,
        Order_id,
        Order_Value, 
        least(Order_Value * 0.1, 20) as Applicable_Discount,
        row_number() over (partition by Customer_id order by Time_of_transaction asc) as row
from    cust_tran_info
order by 2,1
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96b0313b63d80c67b95f86a2f5bd003b)

### $20 cap imposed at a user level

If as a comment on the other answer suggests you are looking to impose a $20 cap cumulatively at a user level rather than at an order level, then you should use this instead:

```
least(Order_Value * 0.1, greatest(0, 20 - coalesce(sum(Order_Value) over(partition by Customer_id order by Time_of_transaction asc ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) * 0.1, 0)))
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed791c9622ec668e8769592857582a42). This may look a little confusing at first but basically does a sum of the discount that has been given on all previous orders (excluding the current order) to figure out how much of the $20 cap (if any) remains to be given for the current order.

Full sql:

```
select  Time_of_transaction,
        Customer_id,
        Order_id,
        Order_Value,
        row_number() over (partition by Customer_id order by Time_of_transaction asc) Customer_Order_Sequence,
        least(Order_Value * 0.1, greatest(0, 20 - coalesce(sum(Order_Value) over(partition by Customer_id order by Time_of_transaction asc ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) * 0.1, 0))) discount_to_be_given_on_current_order     
from    cust_tran_info
order by 2,1
```

Comment: That's not how min works. Please test code before posting.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the comment, have fixed the issue. I meant to type LEAST rather than MIN. Also tested now in the above link.

Comment: @Strawberry fyi updated my answer again to include a solution in case the person wants to impose a cap at a user rather than order level. I can't actually comment on the other answer :/

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this with a window sum in a subquery and arithmetic logic in the outer query, as follows:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when coalesce(sum_discount, 0) > 20 then 0
        when sum_discount + order_value * 0.1 > 20 then 20 - sum_discount
        else order_value * 0.1
    end applicable_discount
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(order_value * 0.1) over(
            partition by customer_id 
            order by time_of_transaction
            rows between unboundeed preceding and 1 preceding
        ) sum_discount
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: Again, I can't help but feel that these checks are unnecessary

Comment: @Strawberry: in my understanding OP wants the *cumulative* sum of discount to not be greater than 20 per customer, so `least()` does not seem to be an option here.

Comment: You might be right - but LEAST could still be used in that instance